# Mostrar otro nombre de archivo en URL con .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, url

Me pregunto si es posible mostrar otro nombre que no sea el verdadero nombre del archivo actual, por ejemplo estar en `localhost/Index2.php` 
Pero mostrar `localhost/Index` sin el .php, aunque realmente estemos en `Index2.php`.

Comment: Si es posible y se llama **reescritura de URL** (URL rewriting)

Comment: Tendrás algún ejemplo?